# spring cloud contract verification at deployment

Tags: spring-boot

I have extensively gone through SpringCloudContract. It is very effective TDD. I want to verify the contract during actual deployment. I have n number of micro-services  (Spring stream:Source/Processor/Sink) and want to allow user to link them when they define a stream (kafka)in dataflow server dashboard. I am passing certain Object in the stream which act as 
 input/out for micro-service. I want to check the compatibility for micro-services and warn the user accordingly. SpringCloudContract facilitate to verify the contract during the develpment time and not a run time.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Spring cloud contract, but I have found a way to start StubRunner but when it trigger the certificate I get following.

2017-04-26 16:14:10,373  INFO main c.s.s.ContractTester:36 - ContractTester : consumerMessageListener >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner@5e13f156
2017-04-26 16:14:10,503 ERROR main o.s.c.c.v.m.s.StreamStubMessages:63 - Exception occurred while trying to send a message [GenericMessage [payload={"name":"First","description":"Valid","value":1}, headers={id=49c6cc5c-93c8-2498-934a-175f60f42c03, timestamp=1493203450482}]] to a channel with name [verifications]
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.input'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"name":"First","description":"Valid","value":1}, headers={id=49c6cc5c-93c8-2498-934a-175f60f42c03, timestamp=1493203450482}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:93)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamStubMessages.send(StreamStubMessages.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamStubMessages.send(StreamStubMessages.java:

The same work fine with Maven install, but not with main class.

```
...
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMessageVerifier
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableIntegration
@Component
@DirtiesContext
public class ContractTester {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContractTester.class);
@Autowired StubTrigger stubTrigger;
@Autowired ConsumerMessageListener consumerMessageListener;

@Bean
public boolean validSimpleObject() throws Exception {
logger.info("ContractTester : consumerMessageListener >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+stubTrigger);
stubTrigger.trigger("accepted_message");
if(consumerMessageListener ==null) {
logger.info("ContractTester : consumerMessageListener >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
}
logger.info("ContractTester >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" +consumerMessageListener.toString());
SimpleObject simpleObject = (SimpleObject) consumerMessageListener.getSimpleObject();

logger.info("simpleObject >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" +simpleObject.toString());
        assertEquals(1, simpleObject.getValue());                       
        //then(listener.eligibleCounter.get()).isGreaterThan(initialCounter);       
        return true;
}
}
```